# How to merge two data frames based on mutual information with python-pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given two data frame, `df1` and `df2`, containing information of `item_id-rating` and `item_id-class`:

```
df1:

B0006IYIMW 5.0
B000A56PUO 3.0
B000AMLQQU 4.0
B000OVNMGE 1.0

df2:

B0006IYIMW iphone
B000OVNMGE samsung
B000AMLQQU htc
B000A56PUO nokia
```

I wish to merge `df1` and `df` to get the full info of `item_id-class-rating`, so the resulting data frame should be:

```
B0006IYIMW iphone 5.0
B000OVNMGE samsung 1.0
B000AMLQQU htc 4.0
B000A56PUO nokia 3.0
```

Please notice that the order of two data frames maybe different.

Could you please tell me how to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you demonstrate what you've tried here? From what I can see `df1.merge(df2)` should just work

Comment: Is `item-id` unique? If so, you could firstly sort the DataFrames by that column and that `merge` or simple add the desired column from one df to the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['B0006IYIMW',5.0],['B000A56PUO', 3.0],['B000AMLQQU', 4.0],['B000OVNMGE', 1.0]],columns=('item_id','rating'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['B0006IYIMW','iphone'],['B000A56PUO', 'nokia'],['B000AMLQQU', 'htc'],['B000OVNMGE', 'samsung']],columns=('item_id','class'))

df_merged = df1.merge(df2,on='item_id')

print df_merged
```

Comment: Thanks, in case I come across this problem, I'll most certainly will use this solution :)

Comment: Definitely perfect solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As usually, when I can't find the solution I start to hack my own, and by the time I've achieved many bad results and finally have the right one, somebody else already posted `one-line` solution :) Here it is anyway

```
import pandas as pd
# the frames are named the same way, and rows are in the same order
# assuming item-ids are unique I've created list of indices
# which corresponds to the index of the elements from df1 in df2
df2_index = [df2['item-id'].tolist().index(df1['item-id'][x]) for x in range(len(df1))]
# now reindex df1 according to the list and reset index!
df1 = df1.reindex(df2_index).reset_index(drop=True)
# now you can simply add the missing column
df2['item-rating'] = df1['item-rating']
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.Index(['B0006IYIMW', 'B000A56PUO', 'B000AMLQQU', 'B000OVNMGE'],
               name='item-id')
df1 = pd.DataFrame([5., 3., 4., 1.],
                   columns=['rating'], index=idx)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['iphone', 'samsung', 'htc', 'nokia'],
                   columns=['class'], index=idx)
```

#### Solution

```
df = pd.concat([df2, df1], axis=1)
```

#### Demonstration

```
print df 

              class  rating
item-id                    
B0006IYIMW   iphone     5.0
B000A56PUO  samsung     3.0
B000AMLQQU      htc     4.0
B000OVNMGE    nokia     1.0
```